dump a pod from kubernetes
I have a docker image running in Kubernetes that I suspect to contain a malicious code, unfortunately I can't download it directly from the docker hub as there is a restriction on where it can be pulled.
Is there a way to dump this container/pod to the local machine and analyze all the files/code in it?
Is there a way to intercept a request from a particular pod and inspect its content?

If your container runtime is Docker, you can export the image using docker save:
docker save <container-image> -o <image-name>.tar

Or if your runtime is contained, you can use the ctr cli to export the image:
sudo ctr -n k8s.io images export <image-name>.tar <container-image> 

Once you have exported the images, you can load them elsewhere and analyze them.
Reference: https://socketdaddy.com/kubernetes/dump-a-kubernetes-pod-for-analysis/

You can copy the files using kubectl cp.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_cp/
